# Is there any use to poisonous potatoes in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a stash of poisonous potatoes in my chest (about 4 1/2 stacks) and did not know what to do with it. It poisons me and cannot be used to tame and breed animals and for composting. Villagers also won't breed with that.

How can I use the potatoes? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the whole point of poisonous potatoes is that they _are_ completely pointless; they're an item that intentionally does nothing useful, and they're fine with that. Stop pressuring them to perform!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms it has been a long time, and i have stuffed that 7 stacks that i ended with in my friend's chests :D

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So I think what you can do is when you are hungry, you can cram poisonous potatoes into your mouth, and then you can restore more hunger bars than a normal potato.

> Interestingly, a poisonous potato actually restores more hunger and gives more saturation than a normal, unpoisoned potato.

([Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Poisonous_Potato))

Additionally:

> To counteract the effects of the poison, you can drink some milk when
> you've done eating the poisonous potatoes- it doesn't have any
> nutritional value, but will cancel the poisonous effects.

([Neil Slater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/79956/neil-slater), via a comment moved to this answer)

Comment: This doesn't seem right; you'll get more hunger and saturation from the poisonous potatoes, but you'll need to use up a lot of that to restore your health from the poison, even if you immediately drink milk or honey. I haven't done the math, but I'd expect normal potatoes to be a better food source overall (and even if they aren't, the whole point of growing potatoes is to bake them, not eat them raw, which isn't an option with poisonous ones).

Comment: Potatoes are worth a lot more when baked.

Answer (score 25):

The only use for the poisonous potato is to eat one to gain the *A Balanced Diet* advancement, and even then you only need a single one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Griefing other players on a multiplayer server.

If you're playing on a multiplayer server, you've got a stash of poisonous potatoes, and you know where another player stores their food, you could potentially sneak into their base, steal their food, and replace it with poisonous potatoes. If they're not paying attention, they could then potentially take and eat those potatoes and get to very low health from the poison damage, then you can finish him off even with a punch.

Comment: The poison effect in minecraft does not kill people. As far as I know, the poison effect only brings someone down to half a heart.

Comment: you can always finish that player off, so you can be shifting nearby, and kill him when he is low  @Sumurai8

Comment: They would have to *really* not pay attention.

Comment: What a diabolical plan! Bwahaha!